# Matching Base64 encoded HMAC-SHA1 strings in iOS/Objective-c Ruby/Rails

Tags: ios, ruby-on-rails, base64, hmac

I know there are a lot of posts about converting NSData to NSString, NSData to Base64 encoded string, generating HMAC etc. but none that seem to answer how to generate matching Base64 encoded HMAC-SHA1 strings in iOS and Rails.

Using the code below, the signatures do not match.

iOS code:

```
NSString *secret = @"xxx";
NSString *data = @"http://someurl?someparams";
const char *cKey = [secret cStringUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
const char *cData = [data cStringUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
unsigned char cHMAC[CC_SHA1_DIGEST_LENGTH];
CCHmac(kCCHmacAlgSHA1, cKey, strlen(cKey), cData, strlen(cData), cHMAC);
NSData *HMAC = [[NSData alloc] initWithBytes:cHMAC length:sizeof(cHMAC)];
NSString *signature = [HMAC base64EncodedStringWithOptions:NSDataBase64Encoding64CharacterLineLength];
```

Rails code:

```
secret = "xxx";
data = "http://someurl?someparams";
hmac = OpenSSL::HMAC.hexdigest(OpenSSL::Digest::Digest.new('sha1'), secret.encode("ASCII"), data.encode("ASCII"))
signature = Base64.encode64(hmac)
puts "HMAC #{hmac}"
puts "Signature #{signature}"
```

iOS output:

```
HMAC <05651433 c9a3d449 5816ded7 80bef87f dc903e4a> 
Signature BWUUM8mj1ElYFt7XgL74f9yQPko=
```

Rails output:

```
HMAC 05651433c9a3d4495816ded780bef87fdc903e4a
Signature MDU2NTE0MzNjOWEzZDQ0OTU4MTZkZWQ3ODBiZWY4N2ZkYzkwM2U0YQ==
```

Using following code I can get them to match. But it feels hacky (use of description and string replacements in iOS side and `chomp` in Rails):

iOS code:

```
NSString *secret = @"xxx";
NSString *data = @"http://someurl?someparams";
const char *cKey = [secret cStringUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
const char *cData = [data cStringUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
unsigned char cHMAC[CC_SHA1_DIGEST_LENGTH];
CCHmac(kCCHmacAlgSHA1, cKey, strlen(cKey), cData, strlen(cData), cHMAC);
NSData *HMAC = [[NSData alloc] initWithBytes:cHMAC length:sizeof(cHMAC)];
NSString *HMACStr = [[HMAC description] stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"<" withString:@""];
HMACStr = [HMACStr stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@">" withString:@""];
HMACStr = [HMACStr stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@""];
HMAC = [HMACStr dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
NSString *signature = [HMAC base64EncodedStringWithOptions:NSDataBase64Encoding64CharacterLineLength];
NSLog(@"HMAC %@", [HMAC description]);
NSLog(@"Signature %@", signature);
```

Rails code:

```
secret = "xxx"
data = "http://someurl?someparams"
hmac = OpenSSL::HMAC.hexdigest(OpenSSL::Digest::Digest.new('sha1'), secret.encode("ASCII"), data.encode("ASCII"))
signature = Base64.encode64(hmac).chomp
puts "HMAC #{hmac}"
puts "Signature #{signature}"
```

iOS output:

```
HMAC <30353635 31343333 63396133 64343439 35383136 64656437 38306265 66383766 64633930 33653461> 
Signature MDU2NTE0MzNjOWEzZDQ0OTU4MTZkZWQ3ODBiZWY4N2ZkYzkwM2U0YQ==
```

Rails output:

```
HMAC 05651433c9a3d4495816ded780bef87fdc903e4a
Signature MDU2NTE0MzNjOWEzZDQ0OTU4MTZkZWQ3ODBiZWY4N2ZkYzkwM2U0YQ==
```

How can I generate matching signatures without using the hacks?

Comment: For anyone looking for the solution, I have posted a gist here: https://gist.github.com/septerr/8851146

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I am not familiar with Rails, but it seems to me that

```
hmac = OpenSSL::HMAC.hexdigest(OpenSSL::Digest::Digest.new('sha1'), secret.encode("ASCII"), data.encode("ASCII"))
```

computes the digest as a *hex string*, whereas

```
unsigned char cHMAC[CC_SHA1_DIGEST_LENGTH];
CCHmac(kCCHmacAlgSHA1, cKey, strlen(cKey), cData, strlen(cData), cHMAC);
NSData *HMAC = [[NSData alloc] initWithBytes:cHMAC length:sizeof(cHMAC)];
```

computes the digest as a `NSData` object, which is just a wrapper for a
sequence of arbitrary bytes.

You probably should change the Rails code to compute the digest as sequence of
bytes as well, instead of a hex string (perhaps using `digest` instead of `hexdigest`?)

Comment: Thanks!! Using `digest` instead of `hexdigest` worked. I no longer have to do any string replacement etc on iOS side. I still have to chomp the signature on Rails to make it match. Not sure why the base64 encoding appends a space in the end in rails while it doesn't in iOs.

Comment: It appears `OpenSSL::Digest::Digest` is deprecated: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21184960/ruby-digestdigest-is-deprecated-use-digest

Comment: Alternative to the deprecated `OpenSSL::Digest::Digest`: https://stackoverflow.com/a/24904850/144088