# Looking for a swift way to generate OAuth 1 signature

Tags: ios, swift, oauth, yelp

I'm working on a small swift program to work with Yelp API over **OAuth-1**. I am looking to generate a HMAC-SHA1 signature.

I have the customer key, secret key , token and token secret.

From what I know, to make an API request with OAuth 1, we need the following attributes :

1. oauth_consumer_key
2. oauth_token
3. oauth_signature_method = (HMAC-SHA1)
4. oauth_signature
5. oauth_timestamp
6. oauth_nonce

How do I generate #4,5,6

I looked other [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4084979/ruby-way-to-generate-a-hmac-sha1-signature-for-oauth), but didn't help.

TIA!

Comment: Have you figured this out without using a third party library?

Comment: Did you get your solution without third party library?

Answer (score 3):

Quite late response but I maintain a very lightweight Swift 3 easy to use extension that adds OAuth 1.0a capabilities to URLRequest.

It's called [OhhAuth](https://github.com/mw99/OhhAuth). Can be easy installed with Cocoa Pods or the Swift package manager.

```
pod 'OhhAuth'
```

I will add an usage example on how to interact with the Twitter API:

```
let cc = (key: "<YOUR APP CONSUMER KEY>", secret: "<YOUR APP CONSUMER SECRET>")
let uc = (key: "<YOUR USER KEY>", secret: "<YOUR USER SECRET>")

var req = URLRequest(url: URL(string: "https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/update.json")!)

let paras = ["status": "Hey Twitter! \u{1F6A7} Take a look at this sweet UUID: \(UUID())"]

req.oAuthSign(method: "POST", urlFormParameters: paras, consumerCredentials: cc, userCredentials: uc)

let task = URLSession(configuration: .ephemeral).dataTask(with: req) { (data, response, error) in

    if let error = error {
        print(error)
    }
    else if let data = data {
        print(String(data: data, encoding: .utf8) ?? "Does not look like a utf8 response :(")
    }
}
task.resume()
```

If you are only interested in the signature, you can use:

```
OhhAuth.calculateSignature(url: URL, method: String, parameter: [String: String],
consumerCredentials cc: Credentials, userCredentials uc: Credentials?) -> String
```

Comment: I am interested only by the signature, but i need my signature is generated with other parameter : oauth_nonce , oauth_timestamp , it's possible ?

Comment: @MilletAntoine `oauth_nonce` and `oauth_timestamp` are part of the standard so my library already does that for you automatically. You can validate this here:
https://github.com/mw99/OhhAuth/blob/master/Sources/OhhAuth.swift#L134

or just take a look at the generated signature string, it will include the parameters.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this library [OAuthSwift](https://github.com/OAuthSwift/OAuthSwift), and if you are working with RxSwift + Moya this one will fit you perfectly [RxSocialConnect-iOS](https://github.com/robertofrontado/RxSocialConnect-iOS)